# Get information from a string using split

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this string:

```
var filePos = "{'Data':'17/02/2015', 'Descrizione':'PROVA AAA', 'Lat':'45.411258', 'Lng':'11.906326', 'Foto':'sdjahvas'}" +
        "{'Data':'18/02/2015', 'Descrizione':'PROVA BAA', 'Lat':'45.411190', 'Lng':'11.906324', 'Foto':'asde'}";
```

I have to put in array some information like Data, Lat, Lng, Index(is progressive).

I use this function:

```
var jsonString = filePos.replace(/\'/g, '"').split('}'),
positionAry;
jsonString.pop();
positionAry = JSON.parse('[' + jsonString.join('},') + '}]');
beaches = positionAry.map(function (obj, index) {
return [obj.Data, obj.Lat, obj.Lng, index+1];
});
```

but the array that return is:

```
var beaches = [
               ["17/02/2015", "45.411158", "11.906326", 1],
               ["18/02/2015", "45.411190", "11.906324", 2],
             ];
```

So I don't want this array, but this:

```
var beaches = [
                   ["17/02/2015", 45.411158, 11.906326, 1],
                   ["18/02/2015", 45.411190, 11.906324, 2],
                 ];
```

In short, i don't want Lat and Lng in inverted commas. How can i do that?

Comment: Try this. `return [obj.Data, parseFloat(obj.Lat), parseFloat(obj.Lng), index+1];`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your JSON string filePos , those values are represented as strings, not as numbers.

If you don't want the "inverted commas" (ie. you don't want them as strings), you have to manually parse them as numbers, using `parseFloat()`.

Answer (score 2):

Parsing a string results in substrings. To get the numeric values for lat and long you need to use parsefloat on the substrings.

```
parseFloat(obj.lat)
```

hope this points you into the right direction